# Undefined method `new' for AST:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, oop, methods

I'm Ruby newbie and I want to test my simple class. However I can't create instance.

This is my code:

```
module AST
    class AST
        def initialize; end

        def parse(src)
            puts src
        end
    end
end

ast = AST.new  # I've also tried 'AST.AST.new'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to test a class, you doesn't need to define a module. Just do like this:

```
class AST
    def initialize; end

    def parse(src)
        puts src
    end
end
ast = AST.new
```

Modules have two major benefits:

1. Modules provide a namespace and prevent name clashes. So, for your codes, you added the AST module, you should create instance like this: `ast = AST::AST.new`
2. Modules implement the mixin facility.

Answer (score 0):

With answer from Aetherus, I've solved it:

```
ast = AST::AST.new
```